# Flutter initialValue Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield

I am making a profile editing page in my program. I am using initialValue in TextFormField but it is not showing username from firebase. I'm creating a controller in initState, it still doesn't show. My codes are as follows. What should I do for this?

```
class _EditProfileState extends State<EditProfile> {
  var userData = {};
  TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController t3 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _bioController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _usernameController = new TextEditingController(text: userData['username']);

    getData();
  }
```

TextFormField

```
TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                controller: _usernameController,
                autofocus: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle_rounded),
                  hintText: userData['username'],
                  labelText: userData['username'],
                  contentPadding:
                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
                )),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see opportunity to solve this problem, but i'm not sure since idk how your getData() function work, if you can translate this logic with your code i think you can solve it.

for now you try to write userData['username'] at _usernameController in initState while userData still "Empty", and then you call `getData()` which i assume you're trying to get user's data and fill userData on it... after getData got called, for sure your _usernameController stays empty because there is no further action to update your _usernameController...

Here is my simple solution

lets say your getData() function will be look like this, and make sure getData() only called on `initState()` to prevent _usernameController got updated accidentally

```
void getData() async {
   ... Do some stuff to load data ...
   setState((){
      userData = data;
      ///Do your things here instead...
      _usernameController.text = userData['username'] ?? "";
   });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it returns null

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextEditingController.fromValue()` like this

```dart
  late final TextEditingController _usernameController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _usernameController = TextEditingController.fromValue(
        TextEditingValue(text: userData['username']??''));
  }
```

And make sure you are getting data on `userData`.

Comment: _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String') , I get an error.

Comment: Can you refer the line, I think `TextEditingValue(text: userData['username']??''` solves the case

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you mean

Comment: Does the update answer solve the issue? And on which part you are getting 1st comment issue

Comment: Only this error appears. The line number does not appear.

Comment: This error occur you don't get any data from reading (null) but it expects to have String. `hintText` and `labelText` are nullable and ok, Issue might be coming from different parts ,

Comment: I am getting data in hintText and labelText. It appears but I can't display it in initialValue.

Comment: if you are getting data initially on UI, Try to recheck controller attachment to the TextFormField and try `flutter clean` then rebuild the app.